# Spring MVC: Bind seperate time and date input field to LocalDateTime

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need a way to let the user specify a time and date and store it in a database.
The 'storing in the database' part works but I'm not sure how to let the user specify it. Is it possible to bind a seperate time and date input field in the form to 1 LocalDateTime object, instead of using `input type="datetime-local"` since Firefox doesn't support it, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1):

One of the jobs of your controller is to map data from the client to the format needed by your DAO.

If client will only send date and time as separate fields, and DAO needs it as a combined value, then that transformation should be done by the controller.

Sure, Spring will help with common transformations, but some transformations will require you to write code.

In this example, Spring can parse date from client to `LocalDate`, and time from client to `LocalTime`, then your controller can combine them and send a `LocalDateTime` to the DAO.

As your programs complexity increases, you'll find that it's rare for the controller input to exactly match the information needed by the DAO, and you have to do more in controllers. Live with it.

Comment: Thank you! I know about converters but could you tell me how to go about converting 2 inputs to 1 in the controller? I can't really find anything about it.

Comment: [`LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.of(localDate, localTime);`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html#of-java.time.LocalDate-java.time.LocalTime-) --- You have now combined two values into one.

Comment: I meant the controller itself, since spring mvc binds the form input to the model attribute. How do I tell it to bind 2 inputs to 1 attribute?